# When buying traffic through Adwords, shouldn't I see an equivalent number of Adsense impressions?

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads

Imagine if I purchase from Google 100 leads to my site through AdWords.

I would expect my AdSense pageviews to be at least 100, so the ratio to be at least 1.

Why is it that I get a 0.95, 0.97, 0.85?
What do you think the issue might be? All cross browser testing has been done and apparently the website works fine with all browsers, mobile included.

Any idea? Is this normal?

Comment: might be because of people clicking but click back before redirects

Comment: Yes that is one reason I didn't consider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad blocking software is playing a big part in this.  The ads may be blocked on your site, but not on Google itself.  So the user clicks on the ad in Google then lands on your site where they don't see ads.

Comment: That is another good explanation I think :)